# Meaning and usage of suffix -まい

Tags: verbs, negation, suffixes, volitional-form

According to the WWWJDIC, the verbal suffix まい can mean:

> (1) probably isn't (doesn't, won't, etc.)
>   (2) don't (doesn't) intend to; intend not to
>   (3) must not; (when used in an imperative sentence) don't

but I've found this sentence in my 日本語能力試験文法問題対策一級 text:

> 何であれ, 必要ならば買わなければなる **まい** 。

Which is the right translation? Or are there other possible translations?

> a) 'No matter what, if it's necessary, I'll probably have to buy it.'
>   b) 'No matter what, if it's necessary, I won't probably have to buy it.'

If it's b), it doesn't make much sense, does it? If it's a), it contradicts the meaning given by the dictionary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- I am not sure if there is meaning 3). What example sentences do yo have in mind?
- Your sentence has まい with meaning 1). In both of your translations, you are dropping `なる` '**be in a good situation**'. That is why your translations do not work. A literal translation is:

> 'Whatever it is, if it's necessary, it probably won't be good if I do not buy it.'

This may sound a bit unnatural. That is because Japanese lacks a single word for "must" (except for `べき` which is weaker in meaning), and you have to say `なければならない` "it will not be well without", `なければなるまい` "it probably will not be well without". A more natural translation is:

> 'Whatever it is, if it's necessary, I probably must/should buy it.'

Comment: I get your point, なるまい　is ならないでしょう。As a matter of fact "must" is なければならない....